Unit test for Lambda expression
I am trying to write a unit test (using Mockito) for my Spring Security config class and it has this code
@Bean
public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper authoritiesMapper() {
    return (authorities) -> {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

        authorities.forEach(authority -> {
           if (OAuth2UserAuthority.class.isInstance(authority)) {
                OAuth2UserAuthority oauth2UserAuthority = (OAuth2UserAuthority)authority;

                Map<String, Object> userAttributes = oauth2UserAuthority.getAttributes();

    userAttributes.getOrDefault("field", List.of())).forEach(a-> mappedAuthorities.add( new SimpleGrantedAuthority(a)));
            }
        });
        return mappedAuthorities;
    };
}

And this is my unit test method which does not cover any line of above code.
@Before(){
this.config = new Config(); //this is Config class which has authoritiesMapper
}

@Test
public void testMapper(){
    //I had some mockito code here but nothing worked.

    this.config.authoritiesMapper();

  
}

If I write any test case, nothing invokes whole method, maybe because of lambda expression. How to write a test when lambda expression like this exist?

Additional note: var output = new ...; input.forEach(x -> output.add(x)) is an anti-pattern (it relies on side-effects). Just use var output = input.stream().collect(toSet())

OAuth2UserAuthority.class.isInstance(authority) is the same as authority instanceof OAuth2UserAuthority

The code does not compile at userAttributes.getOrDefault("field", List.of())).forEach. Even after removing unbalanced parentheses you'll get Cannot resolve method 'forEach' in 'Object'

Lambdas defer execution and are not part of the regular code flow. The body of a lambda expression is only executed when you invoke the lambda. Lambdas map to SAM-types (single abstract method), and if you look at GrantedAuthoritiesMapper, it has a single method: mapAuthorities.
The lambda syntax is more or less syntactic sugar for returning an anonymous class instance (the reality is more complicated than that, but it suffices here as a simplified explanation):
@Bean
public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper authoritiesMapper() {
    return new GrantedAuthoritiesMapper() {
        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapAuthorities(
                final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

            authorities.forEach(authority -> {
               if (OAuth2UserAuthority.class.isInstance(authority)) {
                    OAuth2UserAuthority oauth2UserAuthority = (OAuth2UserAuthority)authority;

                    Map<String, Object> userAttributes = oauth2UserAuthority.getAttributes();

        userAttributes.getOrDefault("field", List.of())).forEach(a-> mappedAuthorities.add( new SimpleGrantedAuthority(a)));
                }
            });
        }
    };
}

So if you want the body of the lambda to be called, then call it:
final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = ...;
this.config.authoritiesMapper().mapAuthorities(authorities); // invoke lambda


PS. Note that your mapper heavily relies on side-effects. I would suggest to either use regular for loops if you want to follow the imperative paradigm or switch to a functional approach:
return authorities -> authorities.stream()
        .filter(OAuth2UserAuthority.class::isInstance)
        .map(OAuth2UserAuthority.class::cast)
        .map(OAuth2UserAuthority::getAttributes)
        .map(attrs -> attrs.get("field"))
        .filter(Objets::nonNull)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

